# "Забудь меня" – значение

Tags: семантика

Слово "забыть" часто употребляется в особом значении, в повелительном наклонении – почти всегда только в нем.

*Забудь меня: твоей любви,

Твоих восторгов я не стою.

Бесценных дней не трать со мною;

Другого юношу зови.*

Как бы вы определили это значение и оценили правомерность с точки зрения современных толковых словарей использование слова "забыть" здесь и вообще в подобном контексте?

Меня оно всегда смущало: есть, говорят, люди, которые специальной тренировкой или с посторонней помощью (сиречь гипноза) могут управлять своей памятью, но таких не сильно много: во всемогущество гипнотизеров я не сильно верю. Да и не об этом речь-то. Хуже того, я даже сформулировать-то толком это значение не могу, хотя интуитивно и/или по контексту всегда понятно, что имелось в виду. Поэтому я считал, что значение такое вполне нормативно, кодифицировано, а его неприятие – мои личные тараканы. А тут вдруг посмотрел по словарям – так нету его.

Повторю вопросы.

1. Объясните это значение – на синонимах или еще как-то.
2. Фиксируется ли оно хоть каким-то словарем, желательно – толковым? И, соответственно, каков реальный уровень его нормативности?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче так. @grizzly, сам, видимо, того не желая, заставил меня посмотреть на всю эту ситуацию под несколько другим углом. Это позволило мне найти ответ на свой первый вопрос.

> Объясните это значение – на синонимах или еще как-то.

Во всех относящихся к делу примерах - от Пушкина до народной побасенки про забывчивую маму речь идет о том, чтобы не давать эмоциональной оценке события, реального, желаемого или прогнозируемого, быть определяющим в собственной оценке этого события.
Грубо говоря, не давать эмоциональному, романтическому мировосприятию возобладать над рациональным.
Обсуждаемо, но я укрепился во мнении, что это достаточно четкая и объемлющая формулировка.

Второй вопрос, о том, фиксируется ли что-то подобное в словарях, по-прежнему открыт.

Answer (score 1):

Намного более подробный толковый словарь русского языка издаётся в Институте русского языка им. В.В. Виноградова под руководством Ю.Д. Апресяна (серия "Активный словарь русского языка"). Слову "забыть" в нём отведено две страницы убористого текста (формат энциклопедический, две колонки), рассмотрены различные значения с примерами употребления. Приведу часть этой статьи. Под сам вопрос более всего подходит значение 1.3, как я понимаю. (Но "Мать может сына позабыть" — это значение 3.1, а вот "забудь о долге [тебе его не отдадут]" — это 1.3 в чистом виде.) Думаю, что "забудь меня..." это тоже 1.3, хотя величина "сдвига" и всевозможные коннотации при прочтении Пушкина у каждого будут индивидуальными.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Я вам плюсанул за демонстрацию того факта, что "забыть" имеет более широкий спектр значений, чем я мог предположить. А заодно - за то, что это изменило мое мнение об Апресяне как не слишком обстоятельном товарище. Всегда приятно узнавать, что кто-то оказался лучше моего мнения о нем.  Но это, пожалуй, всё, за что я могу похвалить ваш ответ. По сути-то я не согласен. Подробнее - ниже.

Comment: *Мать может сына позабыть" — это значение 3.1* - даже представить себе такого не могу. Смысл иной побасенки совсем другой.  Да и управление там другой. Забыть сына и забыть о сыне - это ж совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: *"забудь о долге [тебе его не отдадут]"  - это 1.3* - не-а... ***забудь о ранах, иди в бой***. от чего такого желательного тут можно отказаться? Это не 1.3 точно. Да и под 3.1 совсем не подходит.

Comment: Ну и главное. *Под сам вопрос более всего подходит значение 1.3, как я понимаю* - Да нет же. Тут (и у Пушкина, и в моей *"максиме"* о забывчивой матери, и у меня вообще) речь идет о какой-то отказе от желаемого, а об отказе (сознательном!) о каких-то воспоминаний. По мне так "отвлечься" (по Апресяну - синонимичное какому-то из значений, не понял какому) даже ближе с истине. Но не настолько ближе, чтобы я обрадовался.

Comment: Еще раз почторю. Несмотря на все сказанное - искреннее спасибо. Вроде бы я с вашей помощью нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Обдумаю - напишу.

Comment: @behemothus Не уверен, что я правильно понял аргументы, но спорить не стану. Разве что по поводу управления советую разобраться чуть внимательнее — в словаре явно указываются варианты управления.

Comment: «Смысл иной побасенки совсем другой» — и какой? «Забыть сына и забыть о сыне - это ж совершенно разные вещи» — кто бы спорил: разные. Ну и? «Забудь о долге [тебе его не отдадут]» — двузнаменательное речение ложить в сомнительном разумении не есть хорошо :) «Забудь о ранах, иди в бой. от чего такого желательного тут можно отказаться? Это не 1.3 точно» — это точно 1.3 по Академику: «пренебреги ранами».

Comment: А «максиму» лично я знаю в несколько ином варианте: «Невеста может не отдаться, Машина может поломаться, Мать может сына разлюбить, Но "бросить пить" не может быть!» :)

Comment: @ЕгорСальков И чем он "другой"?  )))) Машина тут за уши притянута. И последняя строчка укорочена. Но это так, в порядке флуда.

Comment: @grizzly *по поводу управления советую разобраться чуть внимательнее* - будьте, пожалуйста, конкретнее. В чем, по вашему высокоученому мнению, я не разобрался, в каком-таком управлении?

Comment: @grizzly *Не уверен, что я правильно понял аргументы* - я вообще не понял, что вы называете "аргументами". Все, что я тут говорил, подходит под определение "Я художник, я так вижу". Это, имхо, не аргумент ни разу.

Comment: behemothus, так он тем и другой, что в нём за уши притянута машина, если о машине можно так выразиться :) Но лично я особой притянутости не вижу: приводятся примеры на тему «многое может подвести», их 3, — фольклорная любовь к троичности общеизвестна... В заключение («четвёртому же не бывать») названо то, что всегда работает безотказно: алкоголь. Я бы даже сказал, что в «моём» варианте имеются признаки эпического схематизма!

Answer (score 0):

Попытка не пытка, как говорил товарищ Берия :)

Дальше будет всерьёз.

1. = повести себя так, как будто забыл о чём-то (или никогда об этом не знал).
2. 

> **забыть**
> -бу́ду, -бу́дешь; забу́дь; забы́тый; -бы́т, -а, -о; св.
>
> *см. тж.* забывать, забываться, забывание
>
> 1.
> а) *кого-что, о ком-чём, про кого-что* Перестать помнить, утратить
> воспоминания о ком-, чём-л.
> Забы́ть номер телефона, название книги. Забы́ть дорогу к дому. Забы́ть обо мне, о вас. Забы́ть про товарищей.
>
> б) отт. *с придат. дополнит. или с инф.* Упустить из виду; не вспомнить
> в нужный момент. Забы́ть купить что-л. Забы́ть взять что-л.
>
> в) отт. *что, о чём.* Не посчитаться с чем-л., пренебречь чем-л. Забы́ть
> приличие. Забы́ть об условностях.
>
> 2.
> *что* Случайно оставить, не захватить с собой. Забы́ть дома очки. Забы́ть зонтик в вагоне.
>
> 3.
> *кого-что* Оставить в пренебрежении, без надзора; забросить. Совсем
> забыл своих рыбок.
>
> https://all_words.academic.ru/23059/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C

Искомое значение — **3.** или **1в)**.

Ещё подходящее значение в [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C#cite_note-19):

> 5. *перен., разг.* полностью отказаться от чего-либо ◆ Конечно, про перерывы и про час в день пришлось моментально забыть. *Е. Павлова, «Вместе мы эту пропасть одолеем! // «Даша»», 2004 г. [НКРЯ]*

Comment: 1. *повести себя так, как будто забыл о чём-то (или никогда об этом не знал).* - да думал я об этом. Не прокатит. В лучшем случае - частное значение, не самое актуальное. Помните народное творчество?  "Мать может сына позабыть, // Невеста мужу не отдаться"... или "Забудь о долге (денежном)". Да и к Пушкинскому тесту не очень вяжется.

Comment: 2. *Искомое значение — 3. или 1в).* - И Кузнецова я смотрел, не извольте сомневаться. Авторы издания по вашей ссылке  у него позаимствовали.  Но - нет. Тут пренебрежение во главу поставлено, а У у Пушкина этого совсем нет. === Или вот еще пример. Человек волнуется перед каким-то завтрашним событием, уснуть не может. Ему дают "совет": *Забудь о нем!* Тут же совсем о другом речь.

Comment: «Тут пренебрежение во главу поставлено» — «пренебрежение» не обязательно есть «презрение»: это значение частное и не самое актуальное :)

Comment: Хотите знать актуальность всех синонимов «пренебрежения» по Словарю синонимов Тришина?  
• абъекция (2)
• безразличие (38)
• бравирование (3)
• брезгливость (11)
• высокомерно-презрительное отношение (2)
• забвение (9)
• игнорирование (12)
• манкирование (4)
• манкировка (3)
• небрежение (6)
• небрежное отношение (6)
• невнимание (15)
• невнимательность (24)
• неглижирование (3)
• недостаток уважения (2)
• отсутствие внимания (4)
• попирание (5)
• попрание (4)
• презрение (7)
• третирование (2)

Comment: «Человек волнуется перед каким-то завтрашним событием, уснуть не может. Ему дают "совет": Забудь о нем!» — и на какой результат этого «совета» рассчитывают те, кто его даёт?

Comment: «В лучшем случае - частное значение, не самое актуальное» — значение более актуальное вы не знаете? Тогда почему вы так уверены, что оно существует? «"Мать может сына позабыть, // Невеста мужу не отдаться"... или "Забудь о долге (денежном)"» — моему определению вполне соответствует. «Мать может сына позабыть» = мать может стать с сыном такой, как будто забыла, что он ей сын. «Забудь о долге (денежном)» = «веди себя так, как будто долга у тебя нет (т. е. не возвращай его)». «Да и к Пушкинскому тесту не очень вяжется» — вяжется. «Держись со мной так, как будто между нами ничего не было».

Answer (score 0):

Подходит следубщее значение из словаря Ожегова и Шведовой:
*упустить из сознания, **перестать держать в мыслях***.

В слове *забыть* прослеживаются два базовых значения: когда что-то исчезает из памяти (вообще здесь не подходит, в повелительном наклонении возможно разве что при гипнозе) и когда человек не вспоминает о чём-то (чаще всего в какой-то момент, но не только).

Здесь же оно употребляется как "не вспоминай". Ну или "делай всё для того, чтоб не вспоминать".

Comment: *Здесь же оно употребляется как "не вспоминай"* - Господь с вами. Если бы оно так было, не было бы и моего вопроса.

Comment: Оно вполне подходит по смыслу.

Comment: Ну ваше право так считать. У меня, как автора вопроса, право категорически с этим не согласиться.

Comment: ПС Тут скорее как раз "вспоминай" может быть частичным синонимом, пусть и очень слабым:  *Вспоминай меня без грусти, // ненаглядный мой.*

Comment: Категоричность здесь не к чему, так как возможным этот вариант является в любом случае. Жаль, что ваша интерпретация слишком запутана и недоступна для понимания. Вам стоит напрямую подставить ваше значение, чтоб прояснить ситуацию. Где "вспоминай"? Последняя строчка сейчас подсказала ответ: здесь немного не тот смысл (то есть не совсем "не вспоминай"), а именно — "делай всё, чтобы забыть [стереть воспоминания из памяти]" (не думать о нём, и клин клином вышибают — звать другого, тогда новые воспоминания заменят старые).

Comment: Я всё сказал, простите. Доказывать что-то в комментариях бессмысленно.

Comment: Да мы не доказываем, а просто выражаем свою точку зрения, ваша до сих пор не ясна.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129482/discussion-between-behemothus-and-oleedd).